# How can I whitelist my Android device?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, firewall, android, ufw

I have been digging and spending a lot of time setting up the most secure SSH environment possible on one of my servers. The last security measure that I want to take is to whitelist my phone on my ssh port using Ubuntu's ufw while off of my home network - which could be on my carrier's network, a friend's home network, Starbucks, etc. (I am using JuiceSSH to ssh in).

I only want my ssh server to be accessible in three scenarios: from my PC on my home network, from my phone on my home network and from my phone off of my home network. The first two are easy because I just had to assign a static IP to my phone and pc in my router's config. The last scenario I am unsure of as the IP of my phone does not seem to be static outside of my home.

(Android 7.0, Ubuntu 16.04)

Is this even possible?
Thanks!

Comment: It can't be done by whitelisting IPs. Each of the different scenarios has a different IP.

Comment: you can definitely white-list multiple ips. The issue isn't that, it's how do I white-list my android device off of my home network? It seems to be always changing, so I'm not sure how to uniquely identify my android device.

Comment: So you definitely didn't understand what I commented. Please read again and understand that if, for instance, you whitelist the Starbucks IP then *any* device using their WiFi is whitelisted. The same for any other scenario you mentioned. As such, *It can't be done by whitelisting IPs*. The only thing unique (not really, but for the sake of the argument) is its MAC address.

Comment: Ah, I thought you were referring to MY 3 proposed scenarios as the second paragraph began, not my starbucks / friend's house / carrier scenarios. The usage of the word 'scenarios' as I used it made me think you were referring to my 3 listed scenarios (which can all be whitelisted).

Based off of what you are saying and some additional research I did, I cannot whitelist starbucks and my friend's IP. However I COULD whitelist my phone on my carrier's network by paying them 500$ for a static phone IP. If you want to write an answer I'd be happy to accept it, otherwise I'll write something up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much digging, I've realized that my question actually had two parts: One is how can I white-list my phone on other local networks and two was how can I white-list my phone on my carrier's network while trying to connect to my server on my home network via SSH.

On other local networks such as a coffee shop network or a friend's network it is doable but not rational because their IP's may keep changing. You could technically white-list incoming requests from those ip's, but they may change at any time.

The more important question was how can I white-list my phone while on my carrier's network, and that would be done by obtaining a static IP from your carrier and then white-listing that IP. Unfortunately, most carriers are going to charge you a good bit of money for this and possibly require that you have a special business account.

The ultimate resolution seems to be using VPN so that you may get into your home network and then identify the device at that time by giving it a static IP as you normally would. Will update my answer with further details if I decide to take that route.

Comment: vpn is a good solution.